# Adobe Search Parameter search folder of PDFs for text

Tags: python, pdf, command-line, adobe

Is there any way that when opening a PDF document from the command line that there can be an advanced search to search multiple pdf's instead of the current document.

the code I have is:

```
subprocess.Popen([path_to_acrobat, '/A','search='+ var + "=OpenActions", path_to_pdf], shell=False)
```

which will open the pdf but just do a search in the current pdf.

Is there any way to search for the words in multiple pdfs from opening one pdf.

I have a large number of PDFs in a folder so I to search all of them using the advanced search option but want to be able to do it from a script or command line with parameters